# Cargo format checker can see hidden spaces VSCode cannot see

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

When running the Rust format checker: `cargo +nightly fmt --check` :

This is what I saw on my terminal:

```
traits::{
-       ConstU128, ConstU32, ConstU8, EitherOfDiverse, EqualPrivilegeOnly, Everything, FindAuthor,
-   },
+       ConstU128, ConstU32, ConstU8, EitherOfDiverse, EqualPrivilegeOnly, Everything, FindAuthor,
+   },
weights::{
```

This is what I have in my code editor:

```
    traits::{
               ConstU128, ConstU32, ConstU8, EitherOfDiverse, EqualPrivilegeOnly, Everything, FindAuthor,
       },
    weights::{
```

somehow Cargo sees some extra spaces in my code,

but my code editor VSCode cannot see it !!??

How can I solve this?

Comment: Might be a `\r\n` vs `\n` issue

Comment: Enable "Render Whitespace" and "Render Control Characters" in the IDE. It might reveal something.

Comment: Or a `' '` vs `'\t'` issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want a quick solution, use this:

```
cargo +nightly fmt
```

That can automatically fix all...

but you will have a lot of code changes detected by the git.